# Broadleaf Commerce: No "Structured Content" admin menu item

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm totally new to Broadleaf Commerce and trying to understand why I don't have any "Structured Content" menu item mentioned [here](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/admin-usage-tutorials/using-structured-content)

I figured out the sql data got moved to a folder called "old" which added the missing menu item: See [here](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/develop-6.0.x/core/broadleaf-framework/src/main/resources/config/bc/sql/old/load_admin_menu_old.sql#L31).

Still after running those SQL statements there's no Content > Structured Content menu item.

My guess was that it is only available in Enterprise Edition but can't find any article/doc/resources which clarifies my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Greeting,
Use this script

```
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_SECTION (ADMIN_SECTION_ID, DISPLAY_ORDER, ADMIN_MODULE_ID, NAME, SECTION_KEY, URL, CEILING_ENTITY) VALUES (-22000, 2000, -2, 'Structured Content', 'StructuredContent', '/structured-content', 'org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContent');

INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID, DESCRIPTION, IS_FRIENDLY, NAME, PERMISSION_TYPE) VALUES (-22918, 'Maintain Structured Contents', 1, 'PERMISSION_STRUCTUREDCONTENT', 'ALL');
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID, DESCRIPTION, IS_FRIENDLY, NAME, PERMISSION_TYPE) VALUES (-22917, 'View Structured Contents', 1, 'PERMISSION_STRUCTUREDCONTENT', 'READ');
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID, DESCRIPTION, IS_FRIENDLY, NAME, PERMISSION_TYPE) VALUES (-22916, 'Read Structured Content Template', 0, 'PERMISSION_READ_STRUCTURED_CONTENT_TEMPLATE', 'READ');
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID, DESCRIPTION, IS_FRIENDLY, NAME, PERMISSION_TYPE) VALUES (-22915, 'All Structured Content', 0, 'PERMISSION_ALL_STRUCTURED_CONTENT', 'ALL');
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID, DESCRIPTION, IS_FRIENDLY, NAME, PERMISSION_TYPE) VALUES (-22914, 'Read Structured Content', 0, 'PERMISSION_READ_STRUCTURED_CONTENT', 'READ');


INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22046, 'org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContent', -22914);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22047, 'org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContent', -22915);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22048, 'org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContentItemCriteria', -22914);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22049, 'org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContentItemCriteria', -22915);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22050, 'org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.Locale', -22914);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22051, 'org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.domain.Locale', -22915);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22052, 'org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContentType', -22914);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22054, 'org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContentType', -22915);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22053, 'org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContentFieldTemplate', -22914);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY (ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22055, 'org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContentFieldTemplate', -22915);



INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_XREF (CHILD_PERMISSION_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22916, -22918);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_XREF (CHILD_PERMISSION_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22915, -22918);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_XREF (CHILD_PERMISSION_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22916, -22917);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_XREF (CHILD_PERMISSION_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22914, -22917);


INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_SEC_PERM_XREF (ADMIN_SECTION_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22000, -22918);
INSERT INTO BLC_ADMIN_SEC_PERM_XREF (ADMIN_SECTION_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-22000, -22917);


INSERT INTO blc_admin_role_permission_xref (ADMIN_ROLE_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-1, -22918);
INSERT INTO blc_admin_role_permission_xref (ADMIN_ROLE_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) VALUES (-1, -22917);
```